# RAD Studio XE2 & Firemonkey - Accessing data in cell of TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have just purchased XE2 and getting to grips with iOS development (I think!!).

I have however failed to see how you can obtain a value from a cell in the XE2 **Firemonkey** implementation of the TStringGrid which is different from the VCL implementation.

I can populate it with values from a SQL Lite database but cannot see how I can get the value from a cell when selected. I have not used LiveBindings at all at this stage to get the values into the TStringGrid which I understand is the 'new' way forward.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Value of a cell:

```
  ShowMessage(StringGrid1.Cells[StringGrid1.ColumnIndex, StringGrid1.Selected]);
```

An example how to use LiveBindings and a StringGrid can you find here (use in Delphi 'File' / 'Open from version control ...'):
https://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/radstudiodemos/branches/RadStudio_XE2/LiveBindings/bindgridlink/fmx

Comment: Your welcome. It's customary to accept the answer by clicking the tick mark icon by the post.